# Monkeypatch imported functions requests module [Pytest]

Tags: python, testing, python-requests, pytest, monkeypatching

I faced a problem that I needed to test a function which called `requests`. The recomemended way is to use `monkeypatch` to avoid the `request` call, but all the resources showed a way to do that with the `requests` module outside the function:

```py
import requests


def test_get_credentials(uri, code):
#the actual function, but rewritten here instead of just being imported

    def mocked_get(uri, *args, **kwargs):
    # this is a request answer mock to avoid calling external servers during tests
        json = {"token_type": "JWT", "access_token": "ioaUSHDAHwe9238hidnfiqh2wr89o"}
        mock = type("MockedReq", (), {})()
        mock.json = json
        obj = mock
        return obj

    monkeypatch.setattr(requests, "post", mocked_get)    

    credentials = requests.post(uri, data=code).json()
    assert credentials == {"token_type": "JWT", "access_token": "ioaUSHDAHwe9238hidnfiqh2wr89o"}
```

But I wanted to use the imported function and didn't find a way to patch the requests module from the imported function. Something like:

```py
import requests
from external_auth import get_credentials

def test_get_credentials(uri, code):
    def mocked_get(uri, *args, **kwargs):
            json = {"token_type": "JWT", "access_token": "ioaUSHDAHwe9238hidnfiqh2wr89o"}
            mock = type("MockedReq", (), {})()
            mock.json = json
            obj = mock
            return obj

        monkeypatch.setattr(requests, "post", mocked_get)

    assert get_credentials(uri, code) == {"token_type": "JWT", "access_token": "ioaUSHDAHwe9238hidnfiqh2wr89o"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found to patch the imported function is through the `__globals__` function attribute changing `get_credentials.__globals__["requests"]` instead of just `get_credentials`. The final code looked like:

```py
import requests
from external_auth import get_credentials

def test_get_credentials(uri, code):
    def mocked_get(uri, *args, **kwargs):
        json = {"token_type": "JWT", "access_token": "ioaUSHDAHwe9238hidnfiqh2wr89o"}
        mock = type("MockedReq", (), {})()
        mock.json = json
        obj = mock
        return obj

    monkeypatch.setattr(get_credentials.__globals__["requests"], "post", mocked_get)

    assert get_credentials(uri, code) == {"token_type": "JWT", "access_token": "ioaUSHDAHwe9238hidnfiqh2wr89o"}
```